# Music does not play after checking checkbox again

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

```
public class Options extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.music01);
    }    

    public void playSong(View view) {
        CheckBox musicCheck = findViewById(R.id.musicCheck);
        if (musicCheck.isChecked()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the checkbox, the music starts playing and when I uncheck the checkbox, the music stops playing. However, when I check the checkbox again the music does not play.

Comment: you need to re-create media player object to do that OR try **mediaPlayer.pause()**

Comment: Keep in mind that `pause()` will replay from the same position, so if you wish to replay the audio from the beginning, then using `stop()` may be desirable. To play in that case, call `prepare()` and then `start()`. Refer to the docs for details about states - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in onCreate

```
musicCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (musicCheck.isChecked()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
});
```